# DSBulk loader version 1.8 : error in loading and connecting to Apache Cassandra

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, dsbulk

I installed Apache Cassandra and DSBulk loader as manual and all it's ok, but when I try to load data with DSBulk it seems to be a problem of connession between the db and the DSBulk. Someone can say to me what happened and how can I solve? That's strange, it's the first time I saw this error. Until today this has never happened to me.

Here the error:

```
dsbulk load -url test.csv -k key1 -t tab1  -delim "," -header false 
Operation directory: /home/User/Desktop/logs/LOAD_20210505-115826-488329
[driver] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=73f04b1b), trying next node (ConnectionInitException: [driver|control|id: 0x435f7dc8, L:/127.0.0.1:57946 - R:/127.0.0.1:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported request opcode: 0 in protocol 6))
Operation LOAD_20210505-115826-488329 failed: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=73f04b1b): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [driver|control|id: 0x435f7dc8, L:/127.0.0.1:57946 - R:/127.0.0.1:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported request opcode: 0 in protocol 6)].
   Suppressed: [driver|control|id: 0x435f7dc8, L:/127.0.0.1:57946 - R:/127.0.0.1:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported request opcode: 0 in protocol 6).
     Caused by: Unsupported request opcode: 0 in protocol 6.
```

After trying the reinstallation of DSBulk, it still remains. Maybe is it something happen with java?

I think that is the first post about, and the problem is very bothersome.

Thank you

According with the first answer received

1. The nodetool status is ok

   Datacenter: datacenter1

   ````
   |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
   --  Address    Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
   UN  127.0.0.1  139,99 KiB  16      100,0%            b3d1b971-59e0-43c7-9392-8dfe1fc2fdeb  rack1```
   ````
2. both listen_address and rpc_address are : localhost

Answer (score 1):

So when I see things like this:

```
Error connecting to Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042
```

...it's almost always because of one of two things.

1. The node is not running.  Validate with `nodetool status`.
2. The `cassandra.yaml` on the local node has a `listen_address` or `rpc_address` is not set to `localhost`.  Note that once Cassandra is listening on a specific IP, attempts to reach it using `localhost` (even locally) will fail.  So double-check the address, and try that.

**Edit:**

I think you're running into this:

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2936

Either way, this is going to require explicitly setting the native protocol version:

```
advanced.protocol.version=V5
```

Comment: Dear @Aaron I update the question so I can show you the status of 1. and 2. you suggested to me.

Comment: so, do you mean that I have to set listen_address and rpc_address on the specific value of 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @TforV Edit made.  Check out the driver support ticket for more details.

Comment: very interesting, infact this is the first time I use Cassandra 4.0...so I'll let you know. Thank you very much for patience.

Comment: I'm not able to solve this...I suppose to turn back the previous version of Cassandra and I'll wait that the problem will be fixed by developers. :(